# Need to use COMM port 2 to get information from a device. .NET doesnt support it though

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

I am writing a VB.NET app that has a piece which needs to send a small command to COM port 2 and get the return result. The problem is .NET doesnt have any support for serial communication seems like. Please help.

I just need to send the command "headtype" and get the result.

Comment: Did you check the System.IO.Ports namespace?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It certainly does, System.IO.Ports.SerialPort, available since .NET 2.0

Comment: And previous to that, there was a free 3rd party tool...  I've used both in several projects now, and it works perfectly  +1 to you and @Austin for good answers, and for beating me to them.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [SerialPort class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx).